# PHP GD messes with JPEG saturation

Tags: php, gd, imaging

I recently got a new camera - Rebel T3i to be specific...
I use GD to resize pictures on the fly on my site. Since getting my new camera GD makes my pictures look blander by removing saturation. I'm not sure why. What is causing this?

Here's what I mean: (see the pic)

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15582820/problem.png

If it matters, here's the auto-resized pic:

http://croar.net/php_scripts/scaler?h=560&img=http://nature.croar.net/raw/627

I can't post more than two links so what the img parameter is in the above URL is the original pic (saturated).

If there's any extra info you need ask and I will provide what is necessary for this to be resolved. Frustrating...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to do the resize?

Comment: WideImage library (basically GD simplified): http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure -- I have noticed something similar in GD before but I was deliberately playing with the colors and it lost saturation.  I would have maybe thought it was the compression levels on the images (but I'm assuming you've looked at that). Might be worth trying with a lossless format to see the difference. The only other thing I can think of is the ratio of the new size, it's possible the extrapolation works differently in different ratios. It may be just something inherent to GD. I'm sorry I don't have something more concrete to offer.

Comment: I found the problem! When saving a RAW to JPEG, Photoshop assigns the Adobe RGB color space instead of sRGB. When converted to sRGB, the photos turn out fine! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nice, glad you found the solution. And thanks for the link to WideImage, I hadn't seen that before and it looks like it might make my life easier.

Answer (score 1):

When saving a RAW to JPEG, Photoshop assigns the Adobe RGB color space instead of sRGB. When converted to sRGB, the photos turn out fine!